# How use querySelectorAll in a element without id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these buttons in HTML code (I cannot change this code):

```
          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34?view=feed">
            <i class="icon-stats"></i>
            Visualizar fluxo do curso
          </a>


          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/discussion_topics/new?is_announcement=true"><i class="icon-announcement"></i> Novo Aviso
          </a>

          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/courses/34/student_view">
            <i class="icon-student-view"></i> Visualização do aluno
</a>
          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/analytics"><i class="icon-analytics" role="presentation"></i> Visualizar análise do curso</a>
      </div>
```

And I want to hide the buttons "Visualizar análise do curso" and "visualizar fluxo do curso". I try this JS:

```
function hidebutton(){
  const btn = document.querySelectorAll("a.button-sidebar-wide");
  btn 
  btn.forEach(btn=>{
        btn.style.display = "none";     
    }) 
}
```

But this hide all buttons.

Comment: Hi @Aline Porfirio, if you care about backwards compatibility note that QuerySelectorAll returns a nodeList type, which is not Iterable on IE10-

if you wish to make this iterable, you need to cast it using [].slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to be able to target specific elements they need to have specific traits, all the buttons are being hidden because all of them match with your selector query.

But, if try to find is unique there you'll encounter the `<i>` tags with some very specific classes.

So you can select those elements and hide their parents as follows:

( you can test this right now )

```js
document.querySelectorAll('i.icon-analytics,i.icon-stats').forEach(i => i.parentNode.style='display:none')
```

```css
a {display:block}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34?view=feed">
    <i class="icon-stats"></i> Visualizar fluxo do curso
  </a>

  <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/discussion_topics/new?is_announcement=true"><i class="icon-announcement">
  </i> Novo Aviso </a>

  <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/courses/34/student_view">
    <i class="icon-student-view"></i>Visualização do aluno </a>
  <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/analytics">
  <i class="icon-analytics" role="presentation"></i> Visualizar análise do curso</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to hide the first and last buttons, you can do this.

```
function hidebutton(){
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll("a.button-sidebar-wide");
  btns[0].style.display = "none";
  btns[btns.length-1].style.display = "none;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors in `querySelectorAll` to get specific elements. If you know how to select the element is CSS, you'll know how to do it in JS by querying the same lines. Like with the `:first-of-type` selector, for example. And then loop over the result of that query to change the `style.display` property.

```js
function hideButtons() {
  const firstAndLastButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`
    a.button-sidebar-wide:first-of-type, 
    a.button-sidebar-wide:last-of-type
  `);
  for (const button of firstAndLastButtons) {
    button.style.display = none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nth-child as long as the button order quantity and order don't change; you can use these as JS selectors as well:

```css
.btn {
background: #efefef;
padding: 1em;
display: inline-block;
}

div .btn:nth-child(1),
div .btn:nth-child(4) {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div><a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34?view=feed">
            <i class="icon-stats"></i>
            Visualizar fluxo do curso
          </a>

          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/discussion_topics/new?is_announcement=true"><i class="icon-announcement"></i> Novo Aviso
          </a>

          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/courses/34/student_view">
            <i class="icon-student-view"></i> Visualização do aluno
</a>
          <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="/courses/34/analytics"><i class="icon-analytics" role="presentation"></i> Visualizar análise do curso</a>
          </div>
```